# Windows mobile message box this.close()?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, messagebox

On Windows mobile 6.1 prof.

I have a messagebox with a yes/no button on it. When I click 'No' option in the messagebox, my whole application shutsdown, how can I simply close the messagebox?

```
                string message = "Application will perform a data download agree?";
                string caption = "";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {

                    navigateForward(WEB_PAGE_NAVIGATE);

                }

                else
                {

                   this.Close();

                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to close the message box. It's a DialogWindow and will close itself when you click any of the options:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show();
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    navigateForward(WEB_PAGE_NAVIGATE);
}
else
{
    // No need to do anything here as the MessageBox is closed automatically.
}
```

The reason your whole application shuts down is because `this` relates to the class you're currently in. I'm guessing that class is your main `Form` and when your main form is closed, the application shuts down.